# How can I format PayPal "Buy Now" generated code?

Tags: html, paypal, code-formatting

First off, the BUY NOW paypal buttons work fine, but they all sit vertically, one on top of another. Before generating paypal's code, I had them organized nicely and symmetrically in two rows.

Here is an example of one of the buttons they generated:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QEB6T733SAMR2">
<input type="image" src="http://www.teegar.net/images/home/ball-1.gif" border="0"       name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The rest of the buttons continue like this, with different quantities.
I tried to remove `</form>` tag from all but the last button, which allowed me to format the graphics, only to find that all the buttons placed my highest quantity in paypals cart.

I know I'm still an HTML newby, but am hoping I can get some help.

[website](http://www.teegar.net)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put them into a table in their own individual cells?

Answer (score 0):

Like Cistoran said use a table like so

```
<table border="0" width="what ever you want the width to be in percentage or pixels">
<tr>
<td>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QEB6T733SAMR2">
<input type="image" src="http://www.teegar.net/images/home/ball-1.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</td>
<td>
then the next one and so on so on
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```